# Getting datastore Info through an API

Tags: google-app-engine

How does one get image data (image url, image info) from datastore through an api?

Is there a tutorial or a project that lets you upload images like FotoRatan but also has an api which can be used to get the image and image info from another website?

Comment: I have no experience with Google API, but if you are dealing with pictures, App Engine Datastore which has a 1MB limit may not be a good option. You should take a look at App Engine Blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to store and serve files (maybe images) using Blobstore: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob

You should also look at [Picasa Web Albums Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)